# Send json in a delete request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await

I need to send a JSON to the API. It is a delete request. With the POST I don't have any problems but here I do...

```
  delReq(req: IReq): Observable<IReqResponse> {
    const url= this.utils.surl;
    return this.http.delete<IReqResponse>(url, JSON.stringify(req))
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<IReqResponse>('delReq'))
    );
  }
```

Appears "No overload matches this call"

Comment: While a body is technically _allowed_ for a DELETE request (https://stackoverflow.com/q/299628/1427878), this is not a very common use case - so the library is probably not prepared for that. So you might need to use the `this.http.request` method instead, and feed it an [`HttpRequest`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) instance, in which you set method, body and what else might be necessary, yourself.

Comment: Typically, you identify the resource you want to delete as part of the URL or query parameters. If you have to rely on a body to transmit more information about the deletion or how it should be performed, you're should likely be making a `POST` request instead (because your request no longer means "delete this resource" but "perform some action that looks like a delete on this resource"). For reference, here are the available overloads for `HttpClient.delete`: https://angular.dev/api/common/http/HttpClient#delete.

Comment: Here's another answer supporting that you shouldn't count on a body in a `DELETE` request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357432/14956277. It's a summary of a mailing list response from [Roy Felding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Fielding) (one of the authors of the HTTP spec and the originator of the REST approach to APIs), so a pretty clear case for why body-less `DELETE`s are the preferred semantics.

Comment: What are you trying to do on the server side that you would need a body anyway?

Comment: Have you tried issuing the DELETE in postman?